# Yellow banner says I marked the question as duplicate - but I didn't!

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36890286/4121347) a few minutes ago.

I voted to close it as "too broad". But now, it has been marked as a duplicate of another question. The yellow banner below the question includes my name in the people who marked it as a duplicate. But I only voted to close it as too broad. So why is my name in that list?

Furthermore, If this is common, then does it happen if I vote to close it as a duplicate of some question **X**, and others vote to close it as a duplicate of some other question **Y**?

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupe of this... the general priority is: 1) if a mod closes a question, it's displayed for that reason, 2) if a gold-badge holder closes it as a dupe (this case) it's closed as that, 3) whatever the *majority* of the other close votes gave.

Comment: Don't we have multiple close reasons on SO?

Comment: @BeshoyHanna Yes we do, but I did not give that reason.

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple close reason displayed at the same time under a question (eg: user1, user2, and user3 vote 'Duplicate' and mod1 and user4 vote 'not a question', both are shown under question)

Comment: @BeshoyHanna I have never seen that.

Comment: @BeshoyHanna that does happen when the majority of users select "Off-Topic".  When that happens the individual sub-close reasons and who voted for them are displayed.  But when the majority reason is something other than off-topic, then only the majority is shown.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267485/is-the-count-for-off-topic-other-reason-less-valuable-than-the-other-reasons/267489#267489 for more info on how it works

Comment: I see. I think the banner needs to be more clear. Perhaps the banner should say: "Users x....n have voted to close this question. a majority of votes were for reason y."

Comment: @BeshoyHanna read the dup and the other linked questions.  Not a new discussion and has long been requested